# MFC ListView Change Item Image

Tags: c++, mfc

I have added items to ListControl, they have images. Now I want to change them, I tried to do GetItem and SetItem, but I was not able. At least I don't know how to get an Item I want. How I can change Image of an item in ListView?

Thanks

P.S.

I've managed to solve it. Here is solution:

This is how to loop

```
LVITEMW pitem;
ZeroMemory(&pitem, sizeof(pitem));

pitem.mask  = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE;
pitem.iItem = <SET INDEX OF YOUR ITEMS HERE, YOU CAN LOOP HERE>;
pitem.iSubItem = 0;
pitem.pszText = new wchar_t[256];
pitem.cchTextMax = 255;
mlist.GetItem(&pitem);
```

And after selecting an item, you can change it's image like this:

```
pitem.iImage = newindex;
mlist.SetItem(&pitem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `CListCtrl::SetItem` is right. You have to set the `nMask` parameter to **LVIF_IMAGE** and provide the index of the image in der image-list in the `iImage` parameter.

Comment: I already added items, like this: mlist.InsertItem(0, User, imgstatus);  imgstatus is index of an image in ImageList and adding items works well. Now how can I select a specific item in ListView and how can I call SetItem on it?

Comment: You need to know the index of the item to change it. Iterate through all items to find a specific one or use `GetNextItem` to find selected items.

Comment: How to know this Item is what I'm looking for? Is pszText good choice? Does pszText contains text when I added it using InsertItem?

Comment: I can loop through all list items by getting ListCount I'll know end of it, but how can I get LVITEMW pointer from each entry?

Comment: Solved it. Edited question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution highlighted in the first post was not working for me. After a short look to Microsoft Documentation, the signature of the SetItem function is:

> BOOL SetItem(const LVITEM* pItem);

pItem should be a pointer to a **LVITEM** which is **const**, which is not really the case in this situation...

However, the next solution is working for me:

```
  // Let's say my CListCtrl is named m_listCtrl

  // Loop on items of CListCtrl
  for( int i = 0; i < m_listCtrl.GetItemCount(); i++ )
  {
     // And then you define a new image with the index iImage for the item i
     m_listCtrl.SetItem(i, 0, LVIF_IMAGE, NULL,
     iImage, 0, 0, 0);
  }
```